# WifiManager.addNetwork succeeds but enableNetwork fails

Tags: android, android-wifi

I can configure and add a network (WPA2-PSK), but when I try to enable it (using WifiManager.enableNetwork), I get a failure. There's no helpful debug information in the log between the calls (other than `W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity idle timeout`). What could this be?

Here's the code:

```
        String quotedSSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = quotedSSID;
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
        conf.hiddenSSID = true;
        conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); // For WPA2
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        Log.w(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Adding " + conf.SSID);
        int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        if (networkId < 0) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Failed to configure " + conf.SSID);
        }
        if (!wifiManager.enableNetwork(conf.networkId, true)) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Failed to enable " + conf.SSID);
        } else {
            Log.i(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Enabled " + conf.SSID);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. When enabling the network, I should've used the new network id, i.e. `networkId` rather than `conf.networkId`

Comment: +1 good hint! In my case `wm.getConfiguredNetworks();` returned `-1` for the network ID of a configured, deactivated network. Using the ID from `addNetwork(...)` did the trick :)